# How does one configure PHPUnit to log to the test database?

Tags: sql, database, testing, phpunit, logging

I am trying to work out how to configure PHPUnit to use the "test database" that is described on this wiki page: http://www.phpunit.de/wiki/TestDatabase However I can't find any documentation on how to enable and configure it.

Has Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I can answer this one my self!

After doing a google for "phpunit depreciated" I came across the following changelog:
http://www.phpunit.de/changeset/5167

Thought I'd leave the question up in case anyone else got confused.

Comment: PHPunit has changed SCM to github now so the link is no longer valid. The gist was that the test database is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

[Chapter 9](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/database.html) has a quick example of initializing your test database.  If you meant how do you go about configuring MySQL (or any other database, for that matter), just let us know and we can get that info for you too.

Comment: Thanks, But what i was specifically looking for was not for configuring the database to be tested but the database that will log the test results and software metrics.

Unfortunately it appears these features have both been deprecated.